# Powershell script to add user to active directory and set static IP

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have seen other similar questions but I am looking to fully automate the process and all of the examples I have found up until now are missing pieces that I need. Also, this is the first poweshell script that I have ever written so it is kind of hacky.

I am looking to add a user to the active directory, but the following settings must be met.

- Add the user to multiple active directory groups
- Set a static IP for the user(normally under the Dial-In tab)
- Set the users password

Here is my current script so far

```
'***Active Directory User Creation***'
$firstname = Read-Host 'First Name:'
$lastname = Read-Host 'Last Name:'
$email = Read-Host 'E-mail:'
$username = Read-Host 'Windows Username:'
$userDefaultPass = Read-Host 'Use Default Password(y/n):'
while($userDefaultPass -ne 'n' -and $userDefaultPass -ne 'y')
{
    $userDefaultPass = Read-Host 'Use Default Password(y/n)'
}

if($userDefaultPass -eq 'y')
{
    $password = 'password012'
}
elseif($userDefaultPass -eq 'n')
{
$password = '/'
$tempPass = '\'

    while($tempPass -ne $password)
    {
        if($password -ne '/')
        {
            'Passwords do not match!'
        }
        $password = ConvertTo-SecureString Read-Host 'Enter Password'
        $tempPass = ConvertTo-SecureString Read-Host 'Re-enter Password' 
    }
}

New-ADUser
-AccountPassword $password
-ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
-DisplayName $lastname + ', ' + $firstname
-Enabled $true
-Name $lastname + ', ' + $firstname
-SamAccountName smithj
-Path “OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=home,DC=local”
-givenname $firstname
-surname $lastname
-userprincipalname ($username + “@test.local”)
-PasswordNeverExpires $true
}

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity TestGroup -Member $Username
```

**Revision:**
Here is my final script

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
# This script creates a user to the active directory
#'***Active Directory User Creation***'
$firstname = $args[0] 
$lastname = $args[1] 
$username = $args[2] 
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $args[3] -AsPlainText -Force
$passwordExpires = $args[4]  
$domain = $args[5]
$userPrincipal = ($username + $domain)

New-ADUser `
-AccountPassword $password `
-DisplayName ($username) `
-Enabled $true `
-Name ($firstname + " " + $lastname) `
-SamAccountName $username `
-Path “CN=Users,DC=myDomain,DC=myCompany,DC=com” `
-givenname $firstname `
-surname $lastname `
-ChangePasswordAtLogon $true `
-userprincipalname ($userPrincipal) `
```

Comment: Ok, so what's your actual question?  Where are you getting stuck exactly?

Comment: I could not find a good example of New-ADUser that specifies groups that the user should be added to. Specifically, if I need to add a user to multiple groups. 

The other issue is that I did not see a way to add a static IP to the user in the active directory.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at [this](http://ss64.com/ps/new-aduser.html) to get more info on `new-aduser`. Also you should use [`add-adgroupmember`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617210.aspx) after you create the user.

Comment: You'll need to use other commands to perform what you want, after you've created the user.  [Add-ADGroupMember](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617210.aspx) and  http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/443507-powershell-get-set-ldap-property-msnpallowdialin should help get you started on those stated goals.

Comment: Okay so it looks like the best approach is to break this up into pieces and use separate commands to achieve the different goals. I will look into this and tell you if I have any more issues. Could you also tell me if you see any noticeable issues with the way I am attempting to set the users password?

Thanks

Comment: Only issue I see could be the `new-aduser` portion, as you use multiple lines without ` at the end of each line.

Comment: I have updated the post with my final script. I am still looking for a way to set the Active Directory IP settings of a user. I'm not sure if there is good Powershell property for this.